# How to fetch array of string elements with SwiftyJSON?

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I have a JSON that might contain an array of string elements and I want to save it to a variable. So far I did:

```
import SwiftyJSON    
(...)
var myUsers = [""]
if(json["arrayOfUsers"].string != nil)
{
    myUsers = json["arrayOfUsers"] //this brings an error
}
```

The error says:

> cannot subscript a value of type JSON with an index of type string

How can I pass this array safely to my variable?

Comment: You check that `json["arrayOfUsers"]` is a *string* and then you try to assign this object to an *array of strings* - it won't work. Please tell us what is `json["arrayOfUsers"]`, is it a string or an array?

Comment: It is an array of string, something like `["5523533","5gdsgdse","5gdsgsdb9","5432523d"]`

Comment: @zcui93 I wrote `myUsers = json["arrayOfUsers"].array` but then I'm getting an error `cannot assign value of type [JSON] to type [String]`

Comment: It's because you declared `myUsers` to be `[""]` AKA `[String]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the array of Strings that SwiftyJSON has prepared when it parsed your JSON data.

I will use `if let` rather than `!= nil` like you do in your question, and we're going to use SwiftyJSON's `.array` optional getter:

```
if let users = json["arrayOfUsers"].array {
    myUsers = users
}
```

If for any reason you get a type error, you can explicitly downcast the SwiftyJSON object itself instead of using the getter:

```
if let users = json["arrayOfUsers"] as? [String] {
    myUsers = users
}
```

Note that your array of Strings is also not created properly. Do like this:

```
var myUsers = [String]()
```

or like hits:

```
var myUsers: [String] = []
```

Both versions are equally valid and both create an empty array of strings.

Comment: Ok, one more question - in this case what about the declaration of `myUsers`? How should I declare it? `var myUsers = [""]` causes an error of type mismatch :(

Comment: `var myUsers = [String]()` or `var myUsers: [String] = []`

Comment: Hm, that super weird, I'm getting this error after those changes: http://imgur.com/RU70gLo What might be wrong here?

Comment: Try my second solution in the answer, with the downcast.

Comment: :) Now it underlines this: `json["array...` and says `Ambiguous reference to member subscript` :|

Comment: I just edited the answer. Try *without* `.array` but *with* the downcast. Sorry, my bad, I wrote too fast previously.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I did what you suggested (without `.array` and with casting), but then I got a warning saying that `Cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type [String] always fails`.. I guess it's a bad sign, isn't it?

Comment: Something's fishy indeed. With my first solution you should get either `[AnyObject]` or `[String]` but not `[JSON]`, and with the second one you should get `[String]` or it should fail, it shouldn't complain like it does... :/

Comment: it looks fishy indeed, especially because the whole code now perfectly works, the warning appears but that's all. I think I will leave it as it is.